# Minimize JOptionPanes (or add them to a JFrame)

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane, taskbar, minimize

Why do JOptionPanes not have these typical buttons like 
**minimize** and maximize? They only have this close button.

Another problem is, that if you click anywhere (outside the
dialog) then the dialog **disappears** and you call it on the
windows **taskbar**, because it is simply **not shown** there.

[image: example]

Comment: Is there maybe a possibility to add or integrate this message dialog to a frame, so that the frame shows it?

Comment: If you aren’t on a mobile device, press Ctrl-S in your browser.  Does the save dialog have a minimize button?  Transient dialogs almost never have it because they are not considered separate from their parent windows.